# Error launching Gmapping node on ROS

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-kinetic, slam-gmapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using ROS kinetic on ubuntu 16 and have installed the binaries for openslam and slam_gmapping using the command

`sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-slam-gmapping and sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-openslam-gmapping`.

However, whenever I am trying to use the gmapping node with ROS, it always throws the following error

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [gmapping/slam_gmapping]: can't locate node [slam_gmapping] in package [gmapping]
```

I am unable to figure out how do I solve this problem. My environment variables are properly defined in the bashrc.

Thanks

Edit 1:

```
dpkg -l | grep gmapping 

dpkg -l | grep gmapping
ii  ros-kinetic-gmapping                         1.3.10-0xenial-20181117-012312-0800                        amd64        This package contains a ROS wrapper for OpenSlam's Gmapping.
ii  ros-kinetic-openslam-gmapping                0.1.2-0xenial-20180809-134859-0800                         amd64        ROS-ified version of gmapping SLAM.
ii  ros-kinetic-slam-gmapping                    1.3.10-0xenial-20181117-032709-0800                        amd64        slam_gmapping contains a wrapper around gmapping which provides SLAM capabilities.
```

**Edit 2:**

My environment is set as follows:
all binary packages installed in

```
/opt/ros/kinetic/share
```

and my custom package are inside

```
~/catkin_ws/src
```

the last two lines in my bashrc contains the following lines:

```
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
source /home/arav/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

The gmapping works when i do
`source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash`.  and `rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping`
But my `gmapping.launch` is inside the `catkin_ws`, so when I `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` or `source ~/.bashrc`, the `gmapping` does not work ad gives the ERROR.

**Edit 3:**

Following @gvdhoorn's advice I cleaned my `catkin_ws` workspace by removing `devel` and `build` folders and `catkin_make` again. This partially solved the problem of finding the `slam_gmapping` node. However, I am getting a new error now. P.S. `gmapping` still does not work.

```
process[gmapping-2]: started with pid [23549]
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/gmapping/slam_gmapping: symbol lookup error: /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/gmapping/slam_gmapping: undefined symbol: _ZN8GMapping14sampleGaussianEdj
[gmapping-2] process has died [pid 23549, exit code 127, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/gmapping/slam_gmapping __name:=gmapping __log:=/home/arav/.ros/log/f518ac08-ff53-11e8-a0af-a0d3c148ec01/gmapping-2.log].
log file: /home/arav/.ros/log/f518ac08-ff53-11e8-a0af-a0d3c148ec01/gmapping-2*.log
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/310470/error-launching-gmapping-node-on-ros/) by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 654 on 2018-12-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-12-12**:
What is the output of `dpkg -l | grep gmapping`?

**Comment by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) on 2018-12-12**:
hi,
grep | gmapping gives :

```
gmapping: command not found
```

but when I run :
`rospack gmapping` it returns `/opt/ros/kinetic/share/gmapping`

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-12-12**:
You must run the full command: `dpkg -l | grep gmapping`.

**Comment by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) on 2018-12-12**:
Hi
Thanks
Yes I ran the full command and the result is same :

```
gmapping: command not found
```

**Comment by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) on 2018-12-12**:
Hi I edited the question, also sorry for the previous comment I put a wrong command for grep gmapping please check edit1 for the grep result.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-12-12**:
So then the question becomes: are the actual files installed.

What is the output of `ls -al /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/gmapping`?

If the `slam_gmapping` binaries are there, try running a `rospack profile` and then try the launch file again.

**Comment by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) on 2018-12-12**:
$ ls -al /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/gmapping

```
total 944
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root   4096 12月  7 13:00 .
drwxr-xr-x 213 root root  36864 12月 10 10:06 ..
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 418184 11月 17 18:33 slam_gmapping
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 496296 11月 17 18:33 slam_gmapping_replay
```

**Comment by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) on 2018-12-12**:
rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping gives the same error that slam_gmapping node not found.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-12-12**:
I'm guessing that you ran `rospack profile` after having `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` before trying anything else. Correct?

Could you please be *very* specific in what you've done when reporting about results. I cannot guess what you're seeing or doing.

**Comment by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) on 2018-12-13**:
Sorry for that. following your advice I can find the `slam_gmapping` node. Sourcing the `catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`, I am getting the error back again since all my packages are in catkin. I have them both in my `bashrc` so I think the problem is of workspace overlaying. How do I solve this, Thanks

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-12-13**:
You have two workspaces? Can you tell us how you set things up?

If you `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash`, do the gmapping pkgs work then?

**Comment by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) on 2018-12-13**:
No I just have one workspace i.e. `catkin_ws/src` where I put all other packages. Rest all other packages are binary installed so they are inside the `/opt/ros/kinetic/share` . The gmapping works when i do source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash. Plz see Edit 2 in the question I updated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok. It looks like something didn't work when you last built your `catkin_ws`.

In a fresh terminal:

```
rm -rf $HOME/catkin_ws/build $HOME/catkin_ws/devel
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
cd $HOME/catkin_ws
catkin_make
source $HOME/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

At this point things should work.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) on 2018-12-13**:
Hi thanks, I do not have access to the PC right now, I will report back tomorrow. Many thanks.

**Comment by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) on 2018-12-13**:
Hi, @gvdhoorn,
This partially solved my problem, but I am getting a new error now. Please see Edit 3 in the question.
Gmapping still does not work.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-12-14**:
Do you have slam_gmapping or openslam_gmapping packages in your `catkin_ws`?

**Comment by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) on 2018-12-14**:
No I don't have them in `catkin_ws`.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-12-14**:
So if we want to be strict, you should now accept my comment with the steps to properly (re)build your workspace as *the* answer. We've solved the issue of `roslaunch` complaining of not being able to find the `gmapping` nodes.

It's bad form to edit a question with a follow-up question.

**Comment by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) on 2018-12-16**:
Hi @gvdhoorn, please add that as an answer. I will post another question for the new problem. Thanks.